# Failed to resolve: com.loopj Getting this message when i tried to sync android studio. I was to the http async dependency

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.londonappbrewery.climapm"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
 implementation'com.loopj.andrdoid: android-async-http:1.4.9'

}
```

Comment: remove space in library and add proper

Answer (score 1):

you should change it to

```
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your dependency like below :

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

Also, please if you are missing to add mavenCentral() then please add.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```